# Is it possible to use an SFSymbol in a Swift Chart for a bar mark?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-charts

I want to use symbols in a bar chart to represent a habit the user specifies. Text can be too long and gets cut off by the next chart.

Here is what I tried:

```swift
Chart {
    ForEach(habitItems) { habit in
        BarMark(x: .value("Type", Image(systemName: habit.symbolHI)),
                y: .value("Tracked", countTrackedDates(for: habit))
                )
        .foregroundStyle(getBarColor(for: habit).gradient)
        .cornerRadius(20)
    }
}
```

`habit.symbolHI` would equal a string for example: `"square.fill"`

I am getting an error:

> Initializer 'init(x:y:width:height:stacking:)' requires that 'Image' conform to 'Plottable'

Maybe there is a way to make an image plottable but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to change?  I don't think you mean to change the bar mark itself, since that is just a bar of colour. Do you want to change the value shown in the axis below the bars? Or in the chart legend?  Is `habitItems` a series?

Comment: Yes, my bad! I would like to display a symbol as the value below the bar mark. Basically the name of the habit below the bar in the chart, I would like to display an SFSymbol instead. I'm not sure that it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, I'll assume you have an array of these:

```
struct Habit: Identifiable {
    let symbolName: String
    let count: Int
    let color: Color
    
    var id: String { symbolName }
}
```

You can just plot the name of the image.

```
BarMark(x: .value("Type", habit.symbolName),
        y: .value("Tracked", habit.count)
        )
```

Then use `chartXAxis` to change the X axis marks to images:

```
Chart {
    ...
}
.chartXAxis {
    AxisMarks { value in
        AxisValueLabel {
            Image(systemName: value.as(String.self)!)
                .font(.system(size: 30))
        }
    }
}
```

I am casting `value` to `String` here because I know I'm plotting strings on the x axis (as in `x: .value("Type", habit.symbolName)`). You can also use `habitItems[value.index].symbolName` if the indices of the x axis marks match the indices of your data (this would work if the data is an `Array`, but would not be the case if it is an `ArraySlice` in the middle of an array for example).